# WooCommerce dynamic stock from API

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Im pretty new to wordpress and woocommerce in general. I have a specific question about the products stock. We have an API available by our provider on which we can check information about a product including their stock. I would like to somehow link our provider's stock to the stock field in our product inside woocommerce. Can the API request be performed real time whenever our clients view the products information? Can this API call result be linked with the product stock inside the WooCommerce product's tab?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, you can...based on the info that you are providing, maybe the shortest way should be to use `ajax` and client side code in order to accomplish that.

Comment: do you think I could reflect this information into the actual product db?